# Como ficaria regex para tratar esse caso?

Tags: java, string, regex

Não estou conseguindo separar palavras dessa forma: No caso eu tenho `CPFConsole`, queria separar para CPF e console.

O código que eu tenho separa assim:
 `([A-Z][a-z]+)|([a-z]{0,})|([A-Z]{2,})`

Mas esse código separa dessa forma: `CPFC` e `onsele`.

Comment: Qual o critério para separar as palavras?

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: `^([A-Z]+)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)`

Comment: Por favor, poste exemplos de como está a string original e como você quer que ela fique.

Comment: @JuniorNunes sua edição foi rejeitada pois você tentou adicionar informações que não eram de autoria do autor do post, e isso não é permitido. Sempre opte por questionar nos comentarios e instruir o autor a fazer a edição, quando forem necessárias informações adicionais.

Comment: @diegofm http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170053/como-ficaria-regex-para-tratar-esse-caso?noredirect=1#comment350469_170055

Comment: @JuniorNunes mesmo assim, o correto é sempre instruir o autor a editar e adicionar, porque na fila não da pra ler todos os comentários que estão na pergunta e na resposta, e esse tipo de edição geralmente sempre é rejeitada.

Answer (score 5):

Se a entrada for `CPFConsole` e você quer só CPF, pode usar essa expressão:

```
(^[a-zA-Z]{3})+
```

Essa expressão pega as três primeiras letras da sua palavra.

Veja funcionando no [OnlineRegex](https://regex101.com/r/GbvJTF/1).

---

Edit: De acordo com o seu comentário, se eu entendi direito, a expressão que o JuniorNunes colocou funciona:

```
^([A-Z]+)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)
```

Veja no [OnlineRegex](https://regex101.com/r/GbvJTF/2).

Comment: Então, mas não seria somente para pegar o CPF, esse seria um dos casos de teste. Ele teria que passar em "ambienteRG10", e deixar cada palavra separada, essa regex eu consegui, agora quando eu tenho uma palavra igual mencionei em cima "CPFConsole" , a ideia nesse caso seria somente separar um grupo de maiusculas até a penúltima letra, antes que elas se tornem minusculas, não sei se ficou claro, desta forma ele separaria (CPF, Console) e me retornaria as duas, o mesmo é valido para um caso assim: "RGCasa", teria que separar RG e Casa.

Comment: @JoseAguiar, esses detalhes devem ser dados antes de ter uma resposta, justamente para evitar respostas que não vão te ajudar. Quando fizer uma pergunta coloque todas as informações relevantes.

Comment: @Taisbevalle você está correta no seu comentário, mas cabe salientar também que, se há alguma duvida, é necessário questionar o OP nos comentarios antes de responder, para evitar esse tipo de situação também, de forma que após a pergunta está clara o bastante para obter uma resposta, esta seja respondida :)

Comment: Mas pelo que ele explicou agora no comentário essa resposta é uma solução para o problema dele!

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @JoseAguiar não esqueça de marcar a resposta como solução (ao lado esquerdo desse post) para que outras pessoas sejam ajudadas também!

Answer (score 3):

#### Critérios (Pelo que compreendi)

- Deve separar palavras
- Para identificar as separação e próxima palavra começa com maiúscula.
- Se todas as letras forem maiúsculas não deve separar. (CPF)
- A letra subsequente a maiúscula é minuscula.

#### REGEX

Seguindo os critérios podemos montar a REGEX assim:

```
pattern : /([A-Za-z])([A-Z][a-z])/g
replace : $1 $2
```

Veja funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/GbvJTF/3).

#### Explicação

- `([A-Za-z])` - Grupo 1, busca 1 letra maiúscula ou minuscula.
- `([A-Z][a-z])` - Grupo 2, busca 1 letra maiúscula, seguída de 1 letra minuscula.

Comment: Simplificado e melhorado, otimo exemplo do regex101 +1

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa separas contando as letras:

```
([A-Za-z]{3})([a-zA-z]*)
```

Irá separar em dois grupos.

> Full match    0-10    `CPFConsole`
>
> Group 1.  0-3 `CPF`
>
> Group 2.  3-10    `Console`

[link](https://regex101.com/r/gIu3Ii/1)

Se precisa de algo mais especifico:

```
(CPF)(Console)
```

[link](https://regex101.com/r/vzQuyr/1)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!